# Unable to generate the table

Tags: python, reportlab

I have a numpy array that is like this :

```
[['aaq', '56.18%', 'CC']
 ['jasl', '0.00%', 'JO']
 ['arw', '1.74%', 'AS']
 ['vcf', '1.07%', 'DA']
 ['hsw', '0.00%', 'LO']
 ['wey', '41.01%', 'IS']
 ['fol', '0.00%', 'MO']
 ['aaw', '0.00%', 'AP'],
 ['sta', '0.00%', 'TT']]
```

that I would like to use as the data of a table. 
In order to do so what I have tried is:

```
doc = SimpleDocTemplate("sectors.pdf",pagesize=A4)
elements = []

data=    [['aaq', '56.18%', 'CC']
 ['jasl', '0.00%', 'JO']
 ['arw', '1.74%', 'AS']
 ['vcf', '1.07%', 'DA']
 ['hsw', '0.00%', 'LO']
 ['wey', '41.01%', 'IS']
 ['fol', '0.00%', 'MO']
 ['aaw', '0.00%', 'AP'],
 ['sta', '0.00%', 'TT']]

t=Table(data)    

elements.append(t)
doc.build(elements)
```

When I run the code I recieve the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sector_alloc.py", line 236, in <module>
    t=Table(data)
  File "reportlab/platypus/tables.py", line 212, in __init__
raise ValueError("%s invalid data type" % self.identity())
ValueError: <Table@0x7F61F6D2ACC0 unknown rows x unknown cols>...     
invalid data type
```

It might have to do with converting the values of the `np.array` to `Paragraphs`? (maybe because they are `str` in the data)
In that case what I did was take each column of the `np.array` separately (`list`) and did :

```
for valor in list:
  list.append(Paragraph('<b>'+valor+'</b>',styleSheet["BodyText"]))
```

And then try to concat again the `lists` to form again the numpy array but didnt worked either ..

Can anybody please help me asign the numpy array as the data for my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be missing commas after most lists in your data list. The list of lists should look like this:

```
data = [
    ['aaq', '56.18%', 'CC'],
    ['jasl', '0.00%', 'JO'],
    ['arw', '1.74%', 'AS'],
    ['vcf', '1.07%', 'DA'],
    ['hsw', '0.00%', 'LO'],
    ['wey', '41.01%', 'IS'],
    ['fol', '0.00%', 'MO'],
    ['aaw', '0.00%', 'AP'],
    ['sta', '0.00%', 'TT'],
]
```

Here is a full example that I tested:

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter
from reportlab.platypus import SimpleDocTemplate, Table

doc = SimpleDocTemplate("example.pdf", pagesize=letter)
data = [
    ['aaq', '56.18%', 'CC'],
    ['jasl', '0.00%', 'JO'],
    ['arw', '1.74%', 'AS'],
    ['vcf', '1.07%', 'DA'],
    ['hsw', '0.00%', 'LO'],
    ['wey', '41.01%', 'IS'],
    ['fol', '0.00%', 'MO'],
    ['aaw', '0.00%', 'AP'],
    ['sta', '0.00%', 'TT'],
]
doc.build([Table(data)])
```

Comment: Thanks it was an issue with the numpy! Given that np.array was made of strs, no lists were generated so that was in fact the problem!